# OnResume camera error.. not able to connect to camera service

Tags: android, android-camera, android-tabhost

In my activity i have 3 Tabost , First is gallery second is camera and third is video when i click on camera its open and user can take picture easily its working fine and on clicking another tabhost other things happen but when i again click on camera and then the app crashes and it shows error "OnResume camera error..  not able to connect to camera service "

below is my on resume code....

```
protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(camera==null){
        camera = Camera.open();
        camera.startPreview();
        camera.setErrorCallback(new ErrorCallback() {
            public void onError(int error, Camera mcamera) {

                camera.release();
                camera = Camera.open();
                Log.d("Camera died", "error camera");

            }
        });
        }
        if (camera != null) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14)
                setCameraDisplayOrientation(context,
                        CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK, camera);
            preview.setCamera(camera);
        }
    }
```

Mainly it shows error here in this line camera = Camera.open();

i tried using camera release in onPause but not working.. please suggest something

Logcat :

```
09-18 15:35:29.595: E/AndroidRuntime(9598): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-18 15:35:29.595: E/AndroidRuntime(9598): Process: com.example.rooshan, PID: 9598
09-18 15:35:29.595: E/AndroidRuntime(9598): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.rooshan/com.rooshan.main.Photo_Activity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
09-18 15:35:29.595: E/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2955)
09-18 15:35:29.595: E/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:146)
09-18 15:35:29.595: E/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
09-18 15:35:29.595: E/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:749)
09-18 15:35:29.595: E/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:413)
09-18 15:35:29.595: E/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:154)
09-18 15:35:29.595: E/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:546)
09-18 15:35:29.595: E/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4478)
09-18 15:35:29.595: E/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18698)
09-18 15:35:29.595: E/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
09-18 15:35:29.595: E/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-18 15:35:29.595: E/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
09-18 15:35:29.595: E/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
09-18 15:35:29.595: E/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-18 15:35:29.595: E/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-18 15:35:29.595: E/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-18 15:35:29.595: E/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
09-18 15:35:29.595: E/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-18 15:35:29.595: E/AndroidRuntime(9598): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
09-18 15:35:29.595: E/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
09-18 15:35:29.595: E/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:407)
09-18 15:35:29.595: E/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:345)
09-18 15:35:29.595: E/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at com.rooshan.main.Photo_Activity.onResume(Photo_Activity.java:93)
09-18 15:35:29.595: E/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1192)
09-18 15:35:29.595: E/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5490)
09-18 15:35:29.595: E/AndroidRuntime(9598):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2945)
09-18 15:35:29.595: E/AndroidRuntime(9598):     ... 17 more
```

Comment: attach logcat for the error

Comment: please check i have updated my question with logcat

Comment: Did you add permissions for Camera in manifest?

Comment: yes.. 

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

Comment: @AnkitSharma Did you get any solution for the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Did you release the camera in onPause?

Like this

```
if (mCamera != null) {
    // Call stopPreview() to stop updating the preview surface.
    mCamera.stopPreview();

    // Important: Call release() to release the camera for use by other
    // applications. Applications should release the camera immediately
    // during onPause() and re-open() it during onResume()).
    mCamera.release();

    mCamera = null;
}
```

You must stopPreview  and release camera in your case otherwise the resurce still blocked from first call...

Comment: After using this i am getting another error in my preview activity where i am showing the clicked pic. i am getting this error 09-18 15:53:03.348: E/AndroidRuntime(11280):  at android.hardware.Camera._stopPreview(Native Method)